# I am experiencing a weird inception like nesting in one of my views and I can't figure out what is wrong with my @object.each block

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**below is a photo of what the view produces**

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK3lA.png)

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="col-md-3">
        <div id="userProfileInfo">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">

            <div id="myContent">
                <%  @song_Objects.each do |object|%>
            <div class="mySongheading" >    
            <%= object[:song_title] %>
            </div>
            <div class="mySongView">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe src="#{object[:url]}"></iframe>
            </div>
            <strong>Musician:</strong> <%= object[:musician] %>

            <button  type="button" class=" btn btn-primary">Share</button>
            <button  type="button" class=" btn btn-danger">Remove</button>

        </div>
            <% end %>

    </div>


</div>
<div  id="suggestionStuff" class"col-md-3">
</div>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(@user) %> |
<%= link_to 'map', mapFinder_path(@user) %>
</div>
```

also @song_Objects is an array of size 7 and only has one object or "hash" **{}** in each. Here is an example of one of the objects printed out in the terminal:

```
 {:song_title=>"ทิ้งไว้กลางทาง ", :muscian=>" Potato", :url=>"http://www.youtube.com/embed/zYNsQ6ibdZs", :tableRef=>21}
```

and yes that Musician's name is Potato apparently he's popular in Thailand.

Also here is the show method from the controller:

```
 def show
     mysongID = []
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
      song_index_table = Mysong.where(:user_id_id => @user[:id])
      songArray = []
      song_index_table.each do |userSong|
      songArray << Song.find_by(:id => userSong.song_id_id)
      mysongID << userSong.id
    end
    @MySongObjectArray = []
     songArray.size.times do |i|
       @MySongObjectArray[i]  = {
        :song_title => songArray[i].song_title.split('-')[0],
        :muscian => songArray[i].song_title.split('-')[1],
        :url => songArray[i].youtube_url , 
        :tableRef => mysongID[i]
     }


     end

  @song_Objects =  @MySongObjectArray


  end
```

Also i am aware that I have a table named :user_id_id, and :song_id_id, it's annoying and ugly but a dumb migration mistake that I have decided is not worth altering, it works just fine, only problem is it looks stupid.

Comment: It looks like you're loading part of your site in an iframe, if that contains the partial with an iframe of itself, then it will duplicate for ever.

Comment: yes you are correct, it was loading the site in the iframe. So what i did was <%= content_tag(:iframe, nil, src: "#{object[:url]}") %>. I got this information from: http://blog.41studio.com/embed-responsive-youtube-video-in-rails-4/

Answer (score 0):

Hi I figured out the answer to my questions from this blog post: http://blog.41studio.com/embed-responsive-youtube-video-in-rails-4/:

anyways what was happening was the iframe I had in standard HTML code   was re rendering the page inside it. The solution was adding a content_tag "<%=  content_tag(:iframe, nil, src: "#{object[:url]}") %>"

Thanks 41studio for the blog post.